# How Split and Find Text Value in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I spilt below Array and print `verificationCode= "value"` in `consle.log`

```
var backup = [{kind=admin#directory#verificationCode, etag="HIWxtAjmBmqPQjjDV2Duo181uSc/ojhx3q8-0EqFY6M1x0NOJ85j1xg", userId=116800256069112846055, verificationCode=37140335}]
```

Comment: This is not a valid js object

Comment: Assuming the backup object is proper in the code, i guess what you want is  `console.log("verificationCode= " + backup[0].verificationCode)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your JS object to be in this format here.

```
var backup = [
{kind:"admin#directory#verificationCode", 
etag:"HIWxtAjmBmqPQjjDV2Duo181uSc/ojhx3q8-0EqFY6M1x0NOJ85j1xg", 
userId:"116800256069112846055", 
verificationCode:"37140335"}
]
```

and then you can use the following to access your values

```
backup[0].verificationCode;
```

Comment: @Xufox you are right, had c# on the brain and it's early morning! I'll update the answer once i wake up and get it right, thanks